# Kubuntu 18.04 issues with font rendering after upgrade to LibreOffice 6.2

Tags: kubuntu, libreoffice, fonts

I'm currently running Kubuntu 18.04 64-bit and running LibreOffice from the official LO PPA. The LibreOffice 6.2.2 release recently rolled out to the PPA. However, after upgrading the LO packages, font rendering in the application is very pixelated (see attached picture). I've tried changing the hardware acceleration, OpenGL, and font antialiasing settings in LO (following instructions [here](https://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/libreoffice-plasma-kde-fonts.html)), as well as the font settings in Plasma to no avail (following instructions [here](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2016/03/how-to-fix-ugly-libreoffice-font-rendering-kde.html)).  Is anyone else experiencing this issue? I greatly appreciate the help!

System information:

- Kubuntu 18.04 64-bit
- KDE Plasma 5.12.7
- Linux kernel 4.18.0-16-generic
- LibreOffice 6.2.2 ([from this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice))
- Intel Core i7-8750H
- Intel graphics

[image: Pixelated menus and canvas text]

Comment: Does the problem go away if you rename *~/.config/libreoffice*? Doing so would make a new "profile". I'm not seeing the issue with 6.2.2. from the same ppa but my kernel is 4.15.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately, the issue still persisted after renaming the folder.